# What is a good "template" Yosys synthesis script?

Tags: yosys

I want to write my own Yosys synthesis script. What is a good template to start with? The manual and webpage contain various examples, but no "authoritative" hello world example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `synth` command runs the recommended script for general-purpose synthesis tasks. See [`help synth`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_synth.html) for a complete list of commands called by this meta-command.

Your script should either borrow from `synth` or simply call `synth` to get the general-purpose stuff done. Many scripts call `synth -run coarse` for the coarse-grain part of synthesis and then continue with a custom sequence of commands for fine grains synthesis. See for example [`synth_xilinx`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_synth_xilinx.html).

For ASIC synthesis to a library in liberty format, use the following script as a starting point:

```
# read design 
read_verilog mydesign.v

# generic synthesis
synth -top mytop

# mapping to mycells.lib
dfflibmap -liberty mycells.lib
abc -liberty mycells.lib
clean

# write synthesized design
write_verilog synth.v
```

A less aggressive set of optimizations is often desired for scripts that do formal verification. In this cases the following sequence of commands is usually a good starting point for the "synthesis" portion of a formal verification flow:

```
hierarchy [-check -top <top-module>]
proc; opt; memory [-nomap]; opt -fast; check -assert
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to put the mycells.lib and mycells.v file in the directory where you invoke yosys. A good example is on yosys's GitHub site under the directory "examples/cmos", where they have placed examples of cmos_cell.lib and cmos_cell.v files.

```
read_verilog counter.v
read_verilog -lib cmos_cells.v

proc;; memory;; techmap;;

dfflibmap -liberty cmos_cells.lib
abc -liberty cmos_cells.lib;;

write_verilog synth.v
```

(Also, if you want a more human readable synthesis output you can modify the .lib and .v file to change NAND and NOR gates into AND and OR gates.)