# How to use 'write_json' command in YosysJS

Tags: json, verilog, yosys

I am new to Yosys and trying to use YosysJS to generate a json description of an input verilog file. 
There is documentation on how to use the command in Yosys. But I do not understand how to use it in YosysJS. I can draw an RTL diagram after different stages of synthesis using following code:

```
    ys.write_file("input.v", document.getElementById("code").value);
    ys.run("design -reset; read_verilog input.v; synth -run coarse; show - 
    stretch");
    YosysJS.dot_into_svg(ys.read_file("show.dot"), "svg");
```

I would like to know what command needs to be run in the ys.run() 
function as a parameter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What commands you'd want run depends entirely on what you are trying to do. See [What is a good "template" Yosys synthesis script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434380/what-is-a-good-template-yosys-synthesis-script) for some pointers. Running `help` will give you a list of all commands available (and `help <command>` will print details for the specified command).